# How to install driver for USB Adapter 802 .11ac (Realtex I think)

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb

I recently purchased a USB wifi 5 adapter and can't figure out how to install the driver on the CD.  There a couple different folders that contain install.sh files.  I saved to my computer and tried right clicking and setting "make executable" and then then when I double click it still just opens in text editor.  I tried some things via the terminal that didn't work.  Please let me know if you have any suggestions.  I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, GNOME version 3.36.8, kernel 5.4.0-60-generic. Thinkpad T530.  Thank you!

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 is the version.